# Convert fixed length file to delimited file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, sh, vim

I want to convert fixed length file to delimited file.

But when I use:

```
sed -e 's/./&,/38'  -e 's/./&,/103'  -e 's/./&,/142'  -e 's/./&,/588' test6.txt
```

I am getting the error:

> suffix too large - 512 max:

and `gawk` is not working in my machine.

Input file is

my input is

```
100211                 XFMASKSWNDAKNOT SET        DASAAMS                                 00KP02/03/2013
```

output should be

```
100211,XFMASKSWNDAK,NOT SET,DASAAMS,00KP,02/03/2013
```

Please help me

Comment: What does your input look like and what is the expected output? I.e. what are you trying to do?

Comment: and what do you mean `gawk is not working on my machine`. do you get an error from `gawk`, or just a msg like `gawk: not found`. Please edit your question with this information. if `..not found..`, try `awk` or `nawk`. Good luck.

Comment: @user3497060, what is your `sed` version.(`sed --version`)

Comment: just replace all consecutive whitespace with a comma. Or am I missing something? This seems to do that `sed 's/[      ]\+/,/g'` Then remove the extra comma between `NOT,SET`

Comment: Squeeze the tabs and then replace them with a comma: `tr -s '\t' < file | tr '\t' ','`

Comment: Use cut: `cut --output-delimiter=, -b 1-6,24-35,36-42,51-57,91-94,95-104 < input.txt`

Comment: I would recommend that look into fixing `gawk`. It is good tool to have aground. You can use `gawk`'s [FIELDWIDTHS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is not necessarily a space or tab separating fields, as in `XFMASKSWNDAKNOT` where `NOT` is in a separate field.

Then you should use the counts of characters in `vim` e.g,

```
:s/^\(.\{23}\)\(.\{10}\)/\1,\2,/
```

will place a coma `,` after the 23rd character and again after 10 more characters. The input

```
100211                 XFMASKSWNDAKNOT SET        DASAAMS                                 00KP02/03/2013
```

yields

```
100211                 ,XFMASKSWNDAK,NOT SET        DASAAMS                                 00KP02/03/2013
```

I didn't do it on your full example as the numbers in the `sed` command you provide don't seem to match the file and desired output.

You can then remove any spaces before a coma:

```
:s/[ ]*,/,/g
```

As suggested by @Roland Jansen, using `cut` and then `sed` to remove spaces before a coma is a good shell way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` like this:

```
echo 100211                 XFMASKSWNDAKNOT SET        DASAAMS   | tr -s " " | tr " " ","
```

First `tr` SQUEEZES multiple spaces to a single space, second one converts spaces to commas.

Or with files:

```
tr -s " " < yourfile | tr " " "," > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' test6.txt
```

The only thing this doesn't satisfy seems to be the last part of your input `00KP02/03/2013`, although I feel it might be a typo and there must be space between `00KP` and `02/03/2013` in which case the above given solution would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this cmd in vim works for your example input:

```
%s/  \+/,/g
```

this handles only `spaces`, if you want consecutive `tab` and `space` to get replaced:

```
%s/\s\{2,}/,/g
```